# How to set value of ant release script for Android application

Tags: java, android, ant, command

I use "ant release -Djava.source=7 -Djava.target=7" to build my android application. But it has 100 errors
The errors like:

```
             1 method getActivity() cannot find the symbol

             2 method findViewById(int) cannot find the symbol.

             3 ...

             4 ...
```

Most of the problems are cannot find the symbol.

But if I use IDE to build this project. everything was fine. So I think Ant release setting has problem, or did not include all lib. Any one can teach me how to set the Ant release to include all lib ? Thank you~